# LINQ object of IEnumerable type does not return a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, asenumerable

Could someone briefly me explain why the I cannot use the `CopyToDataTable` method on the following `linq` object (of `IEnumurable` type)?

```
var query = from r in SourceData.AsEnumerable()
        group r by r["fruitid"] into Dt
        select new
        {
        Group = Dt.Key,
        Sum = Dt.Sum((t)=> double.Parse(t["name"].ToString())) 
        };
```

**Reminder:** My aim consists of retrieving the resulting `DataTable` following the `GroupBy Clause`

Comment: How are you  unable to use `CopyToDataTable`? Is it not showing up in Intellisense? Does it not compile if you try anyway? Is an Exception thrown?

Comment: please tell us the error you get. otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Is `SourceData` is your `DataTable` ?

Comment: @krillgar: it's not showinp up in `Intellisense`.

Comment: @codelahiru: `SourceData` is my `DataTable`, indeed.

Comment: Do you have the `System.Data` namespace included?

Comment: @krillgar: sure, can't miss `System.Data`

Comment: `CopyToDataTable` is defined only for `IEnumerable<DataRow>` (or `DataRow` derived class), while your query result element is anonymous type.

Comment: @dark.vador It was very easy to miss here when you didn't mention it in your question. The first step to debugging is to look for the simplest reasons.

Comment: @IvanStoev: sure, the confusion came while  `debugging`, in particular after expanding the `Results view` stating:" The result view will enumerate the `IEnumerable`  and disclosing the `datarows[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a restriction on the generic type of [CopyToDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx).

Take a look at the declaration of the method:

```
public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : DataRow
{

}
```

If you notice that second line, your `IEnumerable<T>` must be an enumerable of `DataRow`s. What you have is an enumerable of anonymous objects.

Depending on what your `DataTable` is coming from, bound to, etc, there are many other ways to accomplish what you're trying to do, but this is why you don't have that method available.

Comment: Thanks. May I also complete your answer by a useful feedback from [Tim Schmelter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258704/how-to-group-by-the-datatable-and-put-the-result-in-another-datatable) some time ago.