# Convert DataTable to JSON - filter out all children if one is empty

Tags: c#, json, json.net

**Edit 8 Sept**
I'm having trouble parsing a configuration spreadsheet into JSON (generated from a multitude of other spreadsheets)
Initially I'm loading a spreadsheet from Excel using ClosedXML into a Datatable

[image: Excel data source]

After much rewriting, I'm pretty close.  The issue I've got is that I need to exclude any options under pages where there's no But_Type_P1 [aka type] value - the button_num serves no useful purpose if it doesn't have a button type associated with it - it just indicates it's position on an X-Y grid on a hardware device.

I need to work out how I filter out any children if specific ones are null.
If the alias name is empty (or null) we can generate a placeholder for that downstream.  ... I haven't added those to the export yet as they are just cosmetic.

```json
[
  {
    "type": "function",
    "label": "VM",
    "Location": "lhs_front_pc",
    "options": [
      {
        "type": "page",
        "label": "VM|PCs",
        "options": [
          {
            "type": "Source",
            "index": "1",
            "value": "45401"
          },
          {
            "type": "Source",
            "index": "2",
            "value": "45402"
          },
...continues...
      {
        "type": "page",
        "label": "HW|PCs",
        "options": [
          {
            "type": "Source",
            "index": "1",
            "value": "45751"
          },
          {
            "type": "Source",
            "index": "2",
            "value": "45752"
          },
          {
            "type": "Source",
            "index": "3",
            "value": "45753"
          },
          {
            "type": "Source",
            "index": "4",
            "value": "45754"
          },
          {
            "type": "",
            "index": "5",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "type": "",
            "index": "6",
            "value": ""
          },
```

I'm at the point now where I've got a filtered datatable for the function level,
and another one filtered for the pages for each function (up to 5 pages per function)

**Code Snippet**

```cs
public void dtToFunction(DataTable dt)
{

var functionTable = from instance in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    group instance by instance.Field<string>("Panel_Instance") into panel_instance
                    select new
                    {
                        Instance = panel_instance.Key,
                        List = panel_instance.ToList(),
                    };

foreach (var row in functionTable)
{
    logger.Info($"{row.Instance.ToString()}");

    var obj = new JArray();

    var pageTable = from page in row.List.AsEnumerable()
                    group page by page.Field<string>("Page_P1") into page
                    select new
                    {
                        Page = page.Key,
                        List = page.ToList(),
                    };
    var pageObj = new JArray();
    try {
            pageObj = new JArray(
                    row.List
                .GroupBy(r => new { Page = r["Page_P1"] })
                .Select(g => new JObject(
                            new JProperty("type", "page"),
                            new JProperty("label", g.Key.Page.ToString()),
                            new JProperty("options",g.Select(r =>
                            new JObject(
                                    new JProperty("type", r["But_Type_P1"].ToString()),
                                    new JProperty("index", r["Button_Num"]),
                                    new JProperty("value", r["But_Idx_P1"])
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    { logger.Error($"Exception: {exp.Message}");  }
    try
    {
        obj = new JArray(
            row.List
        .GroupBy(r => new { Function = r["Function_Name"], Location = r["Location"] })
        .Select(g => new JObject(
            new JProperty("type", "function"),
            new JProperty("label", g.Key.Function.ToString()),
            new JProperty("Location", g.Key.Location.ToString()),
            new JProperty("options", 
                    pageObj
                    )
                )
            
            )
        );

        logger.Info($"{obj.ToString()}");
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        logger.Error($"Exception: {exp.Message}");
    }
```

I've been through

- [DataTable to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451460/datatable-to-json)
- [Convert DataTable to JSON with key per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138035/convert-datatable-to-json-with-key-per-row#answers-header)
- [How to [group by] the datatable and put the result in another datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258704/how-to-group-by-the-datatable-and-put-the-result-in-another-datatable)
- [How to convert datatable to json string using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979922/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-using-json-net)

Comment: Ok - I am making slow progress, but still tied up in knots.

I've added an initial groupby on the function and location, but have to add a group by at each subsequent level.

                .GroupBy(r => new { Function = r["Function_Name"], Location = r["Location"] })

                .Select(g => new JProperty("Function_Name",g.Key.Function.ToString()

                , new JProperty("Location", g.Key.Location.ToString(),


...
It looks like I have to groupby within a JObject - even though I'm getting an error with adding a JProperty to a JArray